# Is commenting every right brace good/bad style?

Tags: coding-style, comments

I am teaching an upper-division software engineering course and am reviewing every student's code.  Some of my students have picked up the habit elsewhere of adding a comment to the right of every closing brace identifying the statement type, such as:

```
if (x > 3) {
  y = 10;
} //if
```

I have told the students to follow the [Android code style guidelines](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html), which says nothing about this practice.  On what grounds should I tell them not to do this (besides personally not liking it), or should I permit it?

Comment: Unfortunately this question has been put on hold because it is opinion-based. I think there is no opinion involved and the definite answer is that comments at closing braces are considered bad style. Always. As Robert C. Martin and others suggest, functions (and the blocks within them) should be kept short making it more than obvious which block is closed by each closing brace. Comments at closing braces are a consequence of badly structured code (long blocks in particular). In practice, the comments become easily outdated, providing misleading information and making things even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments are for clarifying code and increasing readability.  It's clear enough to most reasonable software developers that the statement is an "if."  Furthermore, many IDEs and editors automatically highlight brackets such as these, so the comment isn't necessary.  Generally, you should save comments for describing what methods, classes and variables do (e.g. in Javadoc), or what subroutines within a method will do.  This is based on the general guideline of making sure everything you add improves the code.

Answer (score 2):

Tell them that they should assume that person who review code knows language syntax and how to program. Comments should be rare, indicate and explain some weird and not obvious code section (for instance the api provided by some library is bugged and some workarounds/hacks are needed). We've got documentation (and unit tests) to explain how to use and how code should behave. For educational purpose you can write small class/module filled with such "comment-documentation", give it to students and ask them what did they learn about code from these comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, most likely this will end up in a discussion based on personal preference - which is not within the scope of stackoverflow. But aI'll answer anyway:

In my opinion, that's a bad thing to do - for multiple reasons.

- It messes up the code. the more comments are in there, the less readable it is. A single `}` in a line tells me, instantly, that the last block ends here. with the comment behind, there is more to read - and no additional info (but people will read anyway, cause they don't know that the comment doesn't include any info... and because people tend to read everything automatically)
- It leads to sloppy indentation. After all, that may even be the reasons people started that in the first place.
- it's unnecessary - if I indet the code in a consistent manner, it shouldn't be necessary to note what was closed, it should be easily visible by just going up to where the last statement with the same indentation level was. In most cases (unbless you're reverse-indenting (or whatever that is called), which I don't like at all) this should be very easy, as there is nothing in between...
- it leads to bigger file sizes. may be invalid on modern systems, but still.

Answer (score 1):

Every time is overkill. It depends on the level of indentation and the length of your function, but these are usually signs that you need to step back and refactor. The only time I explicitly do it is for namespaces in C++

Comment: I use it for C++ namespaces too, since the start of the namespace is so far from the end.